# Installing private nuget package from Github Package registry fails with "Could not find project or directory"

Tags: github, nuget, github-actions, nuget-package, github-package-registry

I'm trying to automate my package update from repo1 to repo2 to repo3. I'm tryying to run a Github action for the same.

```
name : Install Latest Package
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - SOF-4565-AutomatePackageUpdate
env: 
  ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS : true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:  
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3.0.2
      
      - name: PACKAGE package update
        run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORGANISATION/index.json -n github -u ${{ github.actor }} -p ${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text
  
      - name: Install Core package
        run: |
         dotnet add package PACKAGE
         git config --global user.email "USEREMAIL"
         git config --global user.name "USERNAME"
         git add .
         git commit -a -m "Bump to ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}" -m "Version <githubusername_orgname>/<nuget_package_repo_name>@${{ needs.PublishPackages.outputs.sha7 }}"
         git push
```

But i get this weird error from actions log
"Could not find any project in `/home/runner/work/REPO/REPO`"

When I tried installing from my local machine using dotnet add package PACKAGE, I get the following error.
[image]

Also, this is what my nuget.config in github looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Server" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORGANISATION/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="1" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

I'm completely fed up and tired with this update automation for 3-4 days now, any help or suggestion is welcome.